# Trying to extract a list from values in a complex nested XML fields using python

Tags: python, xml

im trying to get a list of the 'RS1/row/DEVICE_ID' fields values and the 'RS2/row/COUNTS' value separately of this xml response i have:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<doc>
<md_dev.get_device_list status="0">
<RS1>
<row ROWNUM="1" DEVICE_ID="56378346" SERIAL="" MAC_ADDRESS="601BECBA14D9" IP_ADDRESS="127.0.0.1" STATUS="A" SMART_CARD_NUM="" CUSTOMER_ID="6473876" CST_NAME="STANDALONE,  " DHCP="N" REGISTRATION_NUM="" REBOOT_STATUS="" DEVICE_NAME="test_device" PRIORITY="" DEVICE_TYPE="phone" />
<row ROWNUM="2" DEVICE_ID="86574563" SERIAL="" MAC_ADDRESS="D9170B346DAF" IP_ADDRESS="127.0.0.1" STATUS="A" SMART_CARD_NUM="" CUSTOMER_ID="6473876" CST_NAME="STANDALONE,  " DHCP="N" REGISTRATION_NUM="" REBOOT_STATUS="" DEVICE_NAME="test_device" PRIORITY="" DEVICE_TYPE="phone" />
<row ROWNUM="3" DEVICE_ID="14134351" SERIAL="" MAC_ADDRESS="4ECE5EA9876D" IP_ADDRESS="127.0.0.1" STATUS="A" SMART_CARD_NUM="" CUSTOMER_ID="6473876" CST_NAME="STANDALONE,  " DHCP="N" REGISTRATION_NUM="" REBOOT_STATUS="" DEVICE_NAME="Linux x86_64" PRIORITY="1" DEVICE_TYPE="phone" />
<row ROWNUM="4" DEVICE_ID="97653524" SERIAL="" MAC_ADDRESS="BC644B736870" IP_ADDRESS="127.0.0.1" STATUS="A" SMART_CARD_NUM="" CUSTOMER_ID="6473876" CST_NAME="STANDALONE,  " DHCP="0" REGISTRATION_NUM="" REBOOT_STATUS="" DEVICE_NAME="test_device" PRIORITY="" DEVICE_TYPE="phone" />
<row ROWNUM="5" DEVICE_ID="76452782" SERIAL="" MAC_ADDRESS="abcd1f89869e" IP_ADDRESS="127.0.0.1" STATUS="A" SMART_CARD_NUM="" CUSTOMER_ID="6473876" CST_NAME="STANDALONE,  " DHCP="N" REGISTRATION_NUM="" REBOOT_STATUS="" DEVICE_NAME="test_device" PRIORITY="" DEVICE_TYPE="phone" />
</RS1>
<RS2>
<row PAGES="1" COUNTS="5" />
</RS2>
</md_dev.get_device_list>
</doc>
```

I have tried, with no success to get it this way:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

...

r = requests.get( ... )

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "xml")

figure = soup.findAll('row')

for i in figure:
    print(i['DEVICE_ID'])
```

But im having this error:

```
(List of devices IDs)

...

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scripts/removeUserDevices.py", line 137, in <module>
    print(i['DEVICE_ID'])
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 1321, in __getitem__
    return self.attrs[key]
KeyError: 'DEVICE_ID'
```

Comment: You are using no explicit parser. Therfore`html5lib` is choosen which converts your `XML` to **valid HTML5**. This lead to `lowercase` tag attributes names. Your `'DEVICE_ID'` becomes `'device_id'`. Use explicit `BeautifulSoup(XML, "xml")` to **not** `lowercase` your `XML` content. Relevant [installing-a-parser](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser)

Comment: You should use lxml with xpath for this - very simple. If you're interested, I can post it.

Comment: Thanks, i will try both approaches, and yes i want your post about lxml with xpath, please @JackFleeting thank you both so much!

Comment: @stovfl i've updated the error in the question, now the first part of the error is gone thanks! but the other error persist, after printing the values from DEVICE_ID, i get that error

Comment: ***" the other error persist,"***: To access tag attributes, you have to use `.attrs`. Do `print(i.attrs['DEVICE_ID'])`. Be aware you are looping the whole `XML` and  in `<row PAGES="1" COUNTS="5" />` there is no `'DEVICE_ID'`. Use: `.findAll('RS1')[0].findAll('row')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using lxml and xpath:

```
Devices = """your xml above"""

from lxml import etree
doc = etree.fromstring(devices)
doc.xpath('//row/@DEVICE_ID')
```

Output:

```
['56378346', '86574563', '14134351', '97653524', '76452782']
```

Comment: i user this like this: devices = doc.xpath('//row/@DEVICE_ID') and i have my list, thank you so much!